# How to load only few hibernate mapping files configred in hibernate configuration instead of all?

Tags: hibernate

Greetings.

I have a hibernate configuration file(hibernate.cfg.xml) in my project configured with 10 hibernate mapping files (.hbm files) and I have a requirement to load only 6 hibernate mapping files instead of 10.

So how can we restrict to load only few mapping files instead of all.

Comment: I'm puzzled: When you don't need the 4 remaining files, why are they deployed at all?

Comment: @mabi he might be thought of using like lazy init.. No issues with his question

Comment: @BalajiReddy you mean like a switch that starts up another session factory at runtime? Well, never had to use that and it would certainly be interesting to hear why this would be necessary.

Comment: @mabi I'm completely aggrieved with your point. But the question got some valid points. Dont compare the question with the existing implementation.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible to my knowledge. Reason is when the ORM engine starts up it need to perform some sanity stuff on environment which includes type registration, type check, parsing configurations, validations and so on. You can turn on logger and find more details. Possibly you cannot skip/snooze mapping configuration load. But you have lazy loading option. Comments are appreciated.